# Problem when selecting a date in calendar overlay

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-calendar, 2019, calendar-view

I created a room booking system using a Sharepoint calendar which is overlayed by multiple lists in SP 2019 On Premise.
The users use the main calendar to see which rooms are booked for the day (day-view).
If they want to book a room in the future they go into the main calendar, click on the date in the top left corner and then choose a room. To book the room, they go into the room list via the navigation pane on the left.

Now the confusion: the date on the left resets to the current date which causes a lot of confusion.

Is there any way that the date gets transferred into the underlaying calendar or do you have any design tip to make this behaviour not so confusing?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be something as simple as having your users look at the overlay calendar to see what's available, but when they want to book something, click on the specific room's calendar & then add the item?

Answer (score 0):

@LookWest99 they do exactly that but they are confused because the date changes as soon as they click on the specific rooms calendar